# Where have the Keyboard Layout Options gone in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 13.10, capslock

In Ubuntu 13.04 it was possible to disable the Caps Lock Key. It was also possible to make the key sequence Ctrl - Alt - Backspace to kill the X-server.

That was all done using System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options.

Keyboard Layout in 13.04 is called Text Entry in 13.10. But the options are no longer available. Where have they gone?

Comment: It is confirmed BUG in RELEASE.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322
(Can't set keyboard layout change to alt+shift, ctrl+shift, etc. )
They broke the input several months ago but proudly announce the release with significant bug that touches millions of users.
Some ways to solve the problem are discussed now, but NONE HELPS so far.
We have to wait for official repair.

Comment: Many of the keyboard layout options can now be modified in [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool).

Comment: @Joni Can you consider adding an answer with some helpful content and useful instructions? Thanks!

Comment: @jokerdino I could if I could find an open question :) Now this one is closed (correctly) as a duplicate, and the  linked question is closed for being off-topic.

Comment: The keyboard options such as disabling the caps lock or enabling ctrl-alt-backspace to kill the X-server are not affected by the bug. For an answer using `doncf-editor`, see (Switch caps lock and escape) [http://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc/365701#365701]