# UbuntuGNOME 13.10 - Problem: Keyboard layout: Control L and Caps Lock swapped

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have a problem in UbuntuGNOME 13.10 which I didn't had in prior
releases: I did a clean install and I don't know if it was already there
or if I may have changed something, but my "Control L" and "Caps Lock"
keys are swapped. How to swap them back? See also the attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ38Q.jpg

I swapped them back using the following, but this is obviously not a proper fix:

```
$ cd ~
$ echo "keycode  66 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L" >> .Xmodmap
$ xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

but the "Keyboard Layout Chart" program shows the keys still swapped. What's the reason for this? How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Keyboard Layout Options dialog is going to come back. You can swap the caps-lock and control keys in [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool), under "Typing."

Screenshot:

[image: gnome-tweak-tool]

Comment: Thanks. Reading this I thought it would work, but it doesn't :\ Really wired. (.Xmodmap was renamed of course) Are you using 13.10?

Comment: It works if I set it to "At bottom left" (and the keys are swapped http://i.imgur.com/fWqRH2W.png) :) This whole thing on 13.10 is buggy but since my problem is solved -- even if not properly(?) -- I set this question to answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you did, but here is the reason:

In the Layout Preferences, there is an Option button, it should open a window like this:

[image]

As you can see, the subtree under "Ctrl key position" has an option to swap Ctrl and Caps Lock. When I activate it this is how looks my preview:

[image]

Desactivating the option brings everything to normal.

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is a bug in UbuntuGNOME 13.10 where this dialog is not available :\ http://askubuntu.com/questions/360320/where-have-the-keyboard-layout-options-gone-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Ok, well, when the bug is solved at least you know how to solve it ;) Is the same path, look for "Options..." then the option in the screenshots.

Comment: There's also nothing with "Options...". So there's no way to open "Keyboard Layout Options" somehow?